# python-nvd3 lineplusbarwithfocus chart error

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, nvd3.js

I was trying to use python-nvd3's linePlusBarWithFocusChart  in one of my projects. But the y4 data, the data on the focus bar shows up something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntJNW.png

As you can see the data is not represented right. Following is the generated script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarWithFocusChart();
    chart.margin({top: 30, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
        .x(function(d,i) { return i });
    chart.height(350);

    chart.color(d3.scale.category10().range());
    chart.y2Axis
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',.2f')(d) });
    chart.x2Axis
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            var dx = data_linePlusBarWithFocusChart[0].values[d] && data_linePlusBarWithFocusChart[0].values[d].x || 0;
            return d3.time.format('%d %b %Y')(new Date(dx));
        });
    chart.y4Axis
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',.2f')(d) });
    chart.y3Axis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
    chart.xAxis
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            var dx = data_linePlusBarWithFocusChart[0].values[d] && data_linePlusBarWithFocusChart[0].values[d].x || 0;
            if (dx > 0) { return d3.time.format('%d %b %Y')(new Date(dx)) }
            return null;
        });
    chart.y1Axis
        .tickFormat(d3.format(',.4f'));
    chart.bars.forceY([0]);

    chart.tooltipContent(function(key, y, e, graph) {
        var x = d3.time.format('%d %b %Y')(new Date(parseInt(graph.point.x)));
        var y = String(graph.point.y);
        if(key.indexOf('Sentiment Rate') > -1 ){
            var y =  String(graph.point.y) ;
        }
        if(key.indexOf('User Rating') > -1 ){
            var y =  String(graph.point.y) ;
        }
        tooltip_str = '<center><b>'+key+'</b></center>' + y + ' on ' + x;
        return tooltip_str;
    });
    chart.showLegend(true);
    d3.select('#linePlusBarWithFocusChart svg')
        .datum(data_linePlusBarWithFocusChart)
        .transition().duration(500)
        .attr('height', 350)
        .call(chart);

return chart;
});
</script>
```

The code that was used to generate the above script is:

```
type = "linePlusBarWithFocusChart"

chart = linePlusBarWithFocusChart(name=type, height=350, x_is_date=True, x_axis_format="%d %b %Y",
                                  color_category="category10")

kwargs = {}
kwargs['bar'] = True
extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": ""}}
chart.add_serie(name="", y=ydata, x=xdata, extra=extra_serie, **kwargs)

extra_serie = {"tooltip": {"y_start": "", "y_end": ""}}
chart.add_serie(name="", y=ydata2, x=xdata, extra=extra_serie)

chart.buildhtml()
```

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong!!

Comment: It looks like the data may simply be out of order. Try ordering the data before passing it to NVD3.

Comment: Thank you!! That was it. The data list is somehow loosing its order when I update it.

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in your context chart looks like it's simply out of order. All you need to do is sort the data before you pass it to NVD3.